# Access Getting a value from the next record

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a database that tracks employee QA data. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfTPw.jpg) of a query I have. The highlighted column indicates what type of QA each record is. What I want to do is change the type of form shown based on this value (its a lookup field so the value is actually numeric) Where I am having a problem is getting the value of the QAType field from the next record in the recordset of the query. Here is the code I am trying.

```
Private Sub Command55_Click()

QAType = NextRecord.[QAType].Value

Select Case QAType

    Case Is = 1
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmRCRviewClaimEdits"
    Case Is = 2
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmRCRviewCredits"
    Case Is = 3
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmRCRviewFC"
    Case Is = 4
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmRCRviewRegCall"
    Case Is = 5
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmRCRviewRegDenials"
    Case Is = 6
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmRCRviewRegWQ"
    Case Is = 7
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmRCRviewRetro"
    Case Is = 8
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmRCRviewRTE"
    Case Is = 9
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmRCRviewStateInst"
    Case Is = 10
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmRCRviewPC"
    Case Else
        MsgBox "The Next QA in the Query doesn't have a QA Type!"
End Select
End Sub
```

I hit an error trying the NextRecord statement which I kinda expected as I pulled it out of nowhere. Can anyone help me find a method that could accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code, assuming your field is also named `QAType` in the recordset:

```vb
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
rs.Bookmark = Me.Bookmark
If Not rs.EOF Then
    rs.MoveNext
    QAType = rs!QAType.Value
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! The field is named QAType. I added your code (replacing my QAType statement) but I got a 3265 Run-time Error "Item not found in this collection" which points to the QAType = rs!QAtype.Value line. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, then obviously, it isn't named `QAType` in the recordset. Can you `Debug.Print QAType.ControlSource`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Debug.Print command. From some searching I know that I type it in the immediate window, but I dont know what the ControlSource would be. I've tried the name of the button and the table. I'm sorry for whats probably a very uninformed question, but I'm just starting out into VBA

Comment: It should be the name you use in the table, or if you have a name with special characters, you can use `rs.Fields("My name that has spaces").Value`

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding. The name of the field in the Table is QAType. if I type "Debug.Print QAType.ControlSource" in the immediate window or just include it after your Endif Statement (but before my Select Case) I get a 424 Error - Object required. I was assuming the I needed to replace "ControlSource" with something.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your form is bound to the query.

Next record:

```
If CurrentRecord <> RecordsetClone.RecordCount Then DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
```

Previous record:

```
If CurrentRecord <> 1 Then DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acPrevious
```

Comment: I dont see in your code how that is going to retrieve the value of the QAType  from that next record. It looks like will  move to the next record in the recordset.

Comment: @Robert Loughrey If the form is bound to the query and you move to the next record, what the value of `Me!QAType` will be? The same as previously?

Comment: No it could be different, and if it is different I want it to open the record using a differnet form instead of the same form that I am currently on.